# Binding number (Integer, Double) attribute of a CoreData entity to a SwiftUI Stepper

Tags: swiftui, core-data

**TLDR;** Number values does not change when using a SwiftUI Stepper bound to a CoreData Entity. Why doesn't it work and what should I do instead?

I've created a simple iOS Project (SwiftUI + CoreData) in XCode.

1. In the Data Model, I have added an attribute to the default `Item` entity called `aNumber`of type `Int16`.

[image: Data Model with the added aNumber attribute]

2. I've created a dummy view called `StepperTestView`, that display a selected `Item` with the option to change `aNumber` using a Stepper.

   ```
    struct StepperTestView: View {

        @State var item: Item

        var body: some View {
            Section("Number") {
                Stepper(value:$item.aNumber, step: 1) {
                    Text("The value is \(item.aNumber)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. I'm passing the `Item` to the `StepperTestView` from the `ContentView`

   ```
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {

                        // Passing the item to the StepperTestView
                        StepperTestView(item: item)

                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
            ...
            ...
   ```
4. When I run the app or test in the Preview, nothing happens when I press the stepper buttons, aNumber remains the same.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to change

```
@State var item: Item
```

To

```
@ObservedObject var item: Item
```

Second, Your `Text` in the `label` has to be in a subview where you can wrap `item` in an `@ObservedObject`.

`@State` is for value types, it isn't capable of showing/listen for changes for an `ObservableObject` such as a CoreData object